How to access child component form field in parent component angular
Parent Component  ts
Obj1={ name:"foo" fname:"Bee"}
Obj2={field1: "data", field2:"data2" , filed3:"data3"}
html :
<form #f="ngForm">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.valid && f.dirty">Submit</button>


 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name/label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="obj1.name">
   
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">fname/label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="obj1.fname">
   
  </div>


<childForm [formData]="Obj2" ></childForm>
</form>

Child Component Form:
@Input() formData:any;

HTML :
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">field2</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="formData.field1">
   
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">field2</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="formData.field2">
   
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">field3</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="formData.field3">
   
  </div>

I need to enable submit button  if child component field  made any changes and also form fields value need to map with  obj2

Use Output Decrotor
